# java grid boundary

Tags: java, arrays, grid

The problem is to find the shortest path on a grid from a start point to a finish point. the grid is a 2 dimensional array filled with 0's and 1's. 1's are the path. I have a method that checks the neighbors of a given coordinate to see if its a path. The problem im having is with the boundaries of the grid. The right and bottom boundary can just be checked using the arrays length and the length of a column. But how would i check to make sure that i dont try to check a point thats to the left of the grid or above the grid?

This is my  method

```
public static void neighbors(coordinate current, int[][] grid, Queue q)
    {
    int row = current.getRow();
    int col = current.getCol();

    if(grid[row-1][col] == 1)
    {
        if(grid[row][col] == -1)
        {
            grid[row-1][col] = grid[row][col] + 2;
        }

        else
        {
            grid[row-1][col] = grid[row][col] + 1;
        }

        coordinate x = new coordinate(row-1,col);
        q.enqueue(x);
    }

    else if(grid[row+1][col] == 1)
    {
        if(grid[row][col] == -1)
        {
            grid[row+1][col] = grid[row][col] + 2;
        }

        else
        {
        grid[row+1][col] = grid[row][col] + 1;
        }

        coordinate x = new coordinate(row+1,col);
        q.enqueue(x);
    }

    else if(grid[row][col-1] == 1)
    {
        if(grid[row][col] == -1)
        {
            grid[row][col-1] = grid[row][col] + 2;
        }

        else
        {
            grid[row][col-1] = grid[row][col] + 1;
        }

        coordinate x = new coordinate(row, col - 1);
        q.enqueue(x);

    }

    else if(grid[row][col+1] == 1)
    {
        if(grid[row][col+1] == -1)
        {
            grid[row][col+1] = grid[row][col] + 1;
        }

        else
        {
            grid[row][col+1] = grid[row][col] + 1;
        }

        coordinate x = new coordinate(row, col + 1);
        q.enqueue(x);

    }

    else
    {

    }

    q.dequeue();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the leftmost and topmost indexes are 0 in your arrays, so just make sure that index-1 >= 0 before indexing into the appropriate array.